# How apply animation transition on ng-view

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart, ng-animate

I'm trying to apply an transition in `ng-view` with angular dart.

HTML:

```html
<ng-view class="main-animation"></ng-view>
```

CSS:

```css
.main-animation.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition: all 3000ms;
    -moz-transition: all 3000ms;
    -ms-transition: all 3000ms;
    -o-transition: all 3000ms;
    transition: all 3000ms;
    opacity: 0;
}
.main-animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The animation doesn't work, the `ng-enter` and `ng-enter-active` class do not appear, and even if I simulate the class putting.

```html
<ng-view class="main-animation ng-enter"><ngview>
```

The content is still rendering. Does `ng-view` in angular dart support animate?

Comment: Did you install the NgAnimate module?

Comment: @Ozan Yes I did. In fact transitions in other elements do work. I think that ng-view do not support this kind of animation.

Comment: I am in the same case, an object new AnimationModule() is installed in my AppModule, animations on class add works fine, but ng-enter does not work on ng-views.

But it's the first time I use AnimationModule, may be i use it wrong.

Comment: @AdrienE Same issue. :(